# R CMD check failing for GitLab pipeline

Tags: r, gitlab-ci, r-package

I have been trying to set up a CI pipeline for my R package development recently by following the walkthrough in [this link](https://www.algorist.co.uk/post/building-a-ci-pipeline-for-r-packages-in-gitlab/). As per the link, I really want to use the 'caching' mechanism of GitLab, though this is causing some issues (see below)

I adapted this tutorial into the following pipeline file,

```
image: rocker/tidyverse:4.2.2
  
stages:
  - test

default:
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p installed_deps
    - echo 'R_LIBS="installed_deps"' > .Renviron

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - installed_deps

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - R -e "devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes--no-manual
```

**Issues**

For this pipeline, `R CMD check`:

- **Scenario 1:** Works if I *don't* add `installed_deps` to `.Rbuildignore`; however, the `R CMD check` terminal output *does* complain a little (warnings plus notes) about the folder sitting in the source package (because e.g. it contains executables and so forth which probably shouldn't sit in a package!), thus I'd like to avoid this setup if possible
- **Scenario 2:** Does *not* work if I add `installed_deps` to `.Rbuildignore`; the `R CMD build` stage works fine but when I come to install the package from source, it fails

When I tried to run the pipeline manually on my desktop (in scenario 2), a brief inspection of `00install.out` revealed the following information:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = cI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called 'data.table'
```

However, this bemuses me a bit because `data.table` is clearly installed into the `installed_deps` folder (I can see it). So what is going on here? Does anybody have any clue how I can fix this so that I can run 'Scenario 2' indefinitely?

Comment: As an alternative to caching you could use my [r-ci](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r-ci) setup (used my many/most/all of my packages, some from work, and others) which relies on [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) for _fast_ and _fully automated_ download of CRAN binaries for Ubuntu _with full system dependencies_.